# Make webpages stay inside a single WkWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, web-applications, wkwebview

I'm trying to sandwich my webapp into a wkwebview for reasons not worth going into but anyway...

Everytime I navigate inside the WkWebView, the page opens up in a different web view which makes it impossible to debug (I need to set break points before the page finishes loading).

Is there any way I can get the website to stay in the same web view or failing that, somehow set breakpoints before the web view comes into being?

I've tried setting alerts early in the code to fake a break point but there's so much async stuff going on I can't find the right point to break.

My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://mywebsite.com");

        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL);
        webView.load(requestObj as URLRequest)
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: are your links using target = '_blank'

Comment: @egarlock, no I don't use the target attribute at all and iirc ´_self´ is the default